# creating a slide show for home page in my web site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a home page slide show... it is something like this.. main navigation and other some text should move on the animation....

```
http://www.bam.com.au/
```

so anybody can tell me what are the things that I need to know to do this kind of slid show... I think jquery will do this for me but I dont know how to do this using jquery.. so can you tell me how create such a slid show using jquery and css.

any comments are greatly appreciated.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fin a LOT of jquery/javascript slideshow scripts on the web, and they are all easy to get started with.

I personnaly like Flexslider. http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: thanks for response.. but I am looking for something similar to the one at www.bam.com.au/ (the text on the image looks a pretty good to me) any idea????

Comment: See Pranav Kapoor answer, he must be right with cycle.js

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be using the jQuery [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

Here is a similar [demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int.html) of what you saw on the mentioned website. (Example 2), just that the website uses a really large image as compared to the demo.
You would also require the [easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery.easing.php) plugin for the effect.